# Some commands don't executed after ajax is completed or successed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In below code after ajax is completed or successed `$(".cdmodels").append(result);` does not executed but two next lines are executed. i have checked different way but it's not solved. please help me.

```
$('.load-more').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var count = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var btn = $(this).button('loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Library.Index())",
        data: { count: count },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        method: 'POST',
        complete: function (result) {
            $(".cdmodels").append(result);
            btn.button('reset');
            btn.attr("data-value", parseInt(count) + 1);

        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

browser debug:

[image]

Comment: Check whether the `cdmodels` element exist. Did you try to debug the code with browser? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: ***two next lines are executed*** because those two lines aren't depend on the result of ajax call. Seems like issue with ajax call response. Try to debug your app and check whether the `result` is coming or not

Comment: yes it's exist. i can debug the code with my browser. it does not return any error but `append` command does not add `result` data.

Comment: If you get the return data as json then you have to use json parse I think.      var message = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran no it return a MVC partial view as string.

Comment: What does `Index` action method returns for the ajax call ? HTML markup or JSON ?

Comment: @Shyju HTML murkup. I also remove `dataType: json` but it's not solved.

Comment: can you show us what is the content of `result` after AJAX call?

Comment: @GangadharJannu i added the image of browser debug in the post.

Comment: @msitworld Try `$(".cdmodels").append(result.responseText);` instead of `$(".cdmodels").append(result);`

Comment: @GangadharJannu Great !!! it worked tnx so much sir.

Comment: @msitworld I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you are working with AJAX calls and if you are struck you should debug as shown below

**Log the response**. `console.log(response)`
**Check for the type of response**. `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(response)`

```
$('.load-more').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var count = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var btn = $(this).button('loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Library.Index())",
        data: { count: count },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        method: 'POST',
        complete: function (result) {
            // In your case it should be result.responseText
            $(".cdmodels").append(result.responseText);
            btn.button('reset');
            btn.attr("data-value", parseInt(count) + 1);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked it using a try/catch block?

```
...
complete: function (result) {
  try{
    $(".cdmodels").append(result);
    btn.button('reset');
    btn.attr("data-value", parseInt(count) + 1);
  }catch(e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong! Watch for 'e' and 'result'");
    debugger;
  }
}
...
```

start with devtools open.

Comment: Actually this was for diagnosing the problem

Comment: You are welcome. Ah and just realized that it wasn't enough to diagnose the problem you were describing since there was no exception. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `complete` callback receives a object with several properties. You cannot directly use that to update your DOM. If you want you can use the `responseText` property.

This should work.

```
$(".cdmodels").append(result.responseText);
```

Or even better, use the `done()` callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Index")",
    data: { count: 2 },
    method: 'POST'
}).done(function (res) {
    console.log('done');
     $(".cdmodels").append(res);
});
```

The `jqXHR.success()`, `error()`, and `complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You should use `jqXHR.done()`, `fail()`, and `always()` instead.